# what's the advantage of using factory method pattern over simple factory?

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory-pattern, factory-method

I am reading about factory method pattern and simple factory. turns out As I can understand, simple factory is enough and I don't see the use case of factory method pattern. Please  read this link, https://www.binpress.com/factory-design-pattern/ , and I'll ask my questions.

1) in simple factory , it says it's bad because it violates the open/closed principle.  I understand that but in factory method pattern what it did still violates the open/closed principle.

```
if ('car'==$toyName) {
            $toy = new NyCar();
        } else if ('helicopter'==$toyName) {
            $toy = new NyHelicopter();
        }
```

If there'll be a new tory for New York, we need to add it here.

2) after reading the link, before it actually reached the better solution, it used this following code. :

```
class NySimpleFactory {
    public function createToy($toyName) {
        $toy = null;

        if ('car'==$toyName) {
            $toy = new NyCar();
        } else if ('helicopter'==$toyName) {
            $toy = new NyHelicopter();
        }

        return $toy;
    }
}

class NyToysFactory {

    public $simpleFactory;

    public function __construct(SimpleFactory $simpleFactory) {
        $this->simpleFactory = $simpleFactory;
    }

    public function produceToy($toyName) {
        $toy = null;
        $toy = $this->simpleFactory->createToy($toyName);
        $toy->prepare();
        $toy->package();
        $toy->label();
        return $toy;
    }
}
```

Then it says,

> The developers finish the new code quickly and hand it over to the US
>   factories. After two weeks, the phone starts ringing in the
>   developers’ office because the New York factory was having production
>   issues. It turns out that the NyToysFactory class has been modified by
>   developers at the remote branch because the staff doesn’t want to do
>   packaging and labeling work. They’ve modified produceToy() by removing
>   its label() and package() functions.
>
> It seems like Simple Factory won’t work in this scenario. We don’t
>   want branches in US to be able to modify produceToy() functions.
>   ProduceToy() should consist of a set of standard procedures and the
>   branches should only be responsible for creating location specific
>   toys. What if they can create an abstract class? And the abstract
>   class they create will have a concrete produceToy()method which will
>   implement a set of standard operating procedurea that all branches
>   have to follow. Inside produceToy(), it calls its own abstract method
>   createToy() to obtain a toy class. This way createToy() is able to
>   encapsulate object creation and, since it’s abstract, it delegates the
>   creation to its subclasses.

**Question is:  a)What does it mean by saying handing over it to US factories?  b) or We don’t want branches in US to be able to modify produceToy() functions.  they can still modify produceToy function, what difference does it make at all if they can't or can change it? I just don't understand why simple factory was bad for the following example at all.**

**No need to read about abstract factory  at that link**

Answer (score 2):

**T**<sub><sup>HIS CODE / PROBLEM</sup></sub>  does not illuminate the Abstract Factory or Factory Method. Deciding which class to instantiate by switching on a parameter is indeed an anti-pattern encouraging open-closed principle violation.

Abstract Factory

The Abstract Factory is all about enforcing a *family* of related classes:

```
abstract class ToyFactory
+ createBear(): ToyBear
+ createElephant(): ToyElephant

class USToyFactory extends ToyFactory
+ createBear(): ToyBear -> creates USToyBear
+ createElephant(): ToyElephant -> USToyElephant

abstract class ToyBear
+ playSound()

class USToyBear extends ToyBear
+ playSound()//play US National Anthem
```

Passing a USToyFactory where a ToyFactory is expected enforces the creation of US toys (USToyBear and  USToyElephant) – this is the power of Abstract Factory.

<sup>Notice the *products*, bears, elephants, etc., are known AoT (ahead of time).</sup>

Factory Method

The Factory Method is all about deferring instantiation to subclasses.

```
abstract class Dashboard
+ createWidget(): Widget

abstract class Widget
+ config()

class StatsDashboard extends Dashboard
+ createWidget: Widget -> return new StatsWidget()

class StatsWidget extends Widget
```

Calling createWidget() returns a Widget, but which concrete Widget to return must be deferred to subclasses (StatsDashboard returns a StatsWidget).

<sup>Notice the creation methods are declared up the inheritance tree, but they are fulfilled down the inheritance tree.</sup>

❧ A reader with a keen eye will see that Abstract Factory methods resemble Factory Methods, coincidence? – no. This is where Factory Method’s name is derived (they fulfill concrete class instantiation).

The confusion regarding “US factories” is valid; this is poor word choice. The author hints this code may be passed around to factory workers which is totally irrelevant and confusing pertaining to the factory patterns.

---

To resolve the switch above, you'll need to realize the obvious: each condition handler is related in some way. In this case, they are all toys.

```
public function createToy($toyName) {
    $toy = null;

    if ('car'==$toyName) {
        $toy = new NyCar();//I'm a Toy
    } else if ('helicopter'==$toyName) {
        $toy = new NyHelicopter();//I'm a Toy
    }

    return $toy;
}
```

Using polymorphism, we can satisfy the open-closed principle by creating a set of sibling classes:

```
abstract class Toy
+ operate()

Car extends Toy

Helicopter extends Toy

some_toy.operate();
```

Adding to the switch cases is nothing more than creating another sibling class.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Rafael.  LEt's talk about the difference between factory method and simple factory.  I can do anything with simple factory, why to use factory method pattern at all?

Comment: The Factory Method is about deferring instantiation to subclasses. This is important when you are creating interfaces that create objects but cannot foretell which objects will be created.

Comment: Can we discuss it in a private chat or something? I've learned lot about this pattern but still confuses me somehow. The questions I have will take lots of time here . Thanks in advance

Comment: So, instead of using the `switch` (`if/else`), and letting `createToy` choose the subclass, we should pass the sublclass in as an argument and just let `createToy` instantiate it?

Comment: @Rafael If the factory method relies on DI instead of some parameter passed on to a switch like in the simple factory, how is it used as a factory which can produce different products at runtime? Doesn't the factory method ever use a switch or some control logic to decide which proudct or product creator to instantiate? If that's buried in a DI container, how would you make that container to return different types of instances for the same interface?

Comment: @ΕГИІИО I removed the DI statement since it was confusing. However, the factory method knows which product to create merely by being invoked via single dispatch.

Comment: @ΕГИІИО Yes, control logic will be required by the client to decide which class (with a factory method) to instantiate, but that control logic should absolutely not be in any factory methods. That defeats the purpose of the design pattern.

Comment: @Rafael Hmm so if I understood it correctly, when you implement the factory method, you sort of still need a simple factory (or similar code) at the client to spin things up. Have you come across any sample code showing this wireup? probably minus the DI part? The factory method trips me out every time.

Comment: @ΕГИІИО Exactly. Keep in mind is that this is just an example of polymorphism and nothing more. It's just a common use case of polymorphism worthy of a name. The main idea of polymorphism is to keep code generic, thus reusable, so that clients don't need to know what they're working with. This allows us to *push concrete decisions out to clients* so  that we end up with a "generic core" and "a little concrete shell" (being the non-generic aspect of the code).

Comment: @ΕГИІИО You *really* want a significant generic core; that means you get a lot of reuse. Plus, generic code can be extracted to a library. I question code that has a thick non-reusable shell, because, let's face it, most code does the same thing (more or less) and it's rare that something is *that* differentiated.

Comment: @ΕГИІИО That said, that doesn't mean that everything that could be generic should be generic. That would increase complexity unnecessarily, i.e., over-engineering. It depends on the goal, domain, and use case, e.g., what is likely to change over time, etc., etc., ... Most abstractions are better deferred to the time they are needed, i.e., introduced organically, on demand, rather than eagerly.